# Unity Button unable to call method

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, methods, onclick

I am trying to call a method from a button in Unity but apparently i see a different UI than everyone else.

[image]

I don't see any drop down to select the available methods, although they exist. what do i do wrong? I added "Play" in the Method Name field to run the Play() method but it does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the inspector in the Debug mode. Change this in the right-top corner to `Normal`.
[image]